# Find closest point of a div border (relative to another div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have been looking for an answer for a long time now and can't figure it out. What I need to find is, having 2 div's, the coordinates of the closest point at the border of the last div, relative to the first one.

[image: Capture]

As you can see, right now I am not able to get it so I'm linking fixed points of each div using a SVG. I would like to link the closest points at the border of each div.

Thanks so much

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Richacinas/xjxm43hb/

Comment: any thoughts?? I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: your fiddle is broken, so no thoughts

Comment: Ouch!! sorry.. I shared it through HTTPS.. my mistake. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Richacinas/xjxm43hb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Finally, the problem was pointless and what I did was connect the center of each div and then made sure that my DIV is showing on top of my canvas.

No matter how the elements are positioned, it always looks perfect.

Thanks anyway!